# Split array in the best possible way with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, split

I am looking for an algorithm name, preferably a library that can take an array and split it between functions in the best way possible.
I don't care about the complexity (it's for a very low data set).
Recursive check would suffice.

A nice example would be array:

```
const list = [{gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}, {gender: "male"}]
```

So if we run it with the special function

```
specialFunc(list, [(val) => val === 'female', (val) => val === 'male']);
```

We would be getting this

```
[
 [{gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}],
 [{gender: "male"}]
]
```

Because this is the best possible split we can get.

However, if we run it by this function:

```
specialFunc(list, [(val) => !!val, (val) => val === 'male']);
```

I would be getting this:

```
[
 [{gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}],
 [{gender: "male"}]
]
```

"the best way possible" means that the number distance (of array length) between each array should be the lowest, and the number of records in each array should be the maximum possible.

I have searched npmjs and github a lot but couldn't find anything.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: To understand the split criteria better: Is this kind of like a pattern match where you are start with the more specific match and then look at broader ones? The second example suggests that. You check for "male" as it is more specific compared to `true` and then match the remaining against `true`.

Comment: So basically we can look at groups and subgroups.
But for my example, I would prefer to run every possible solution to find the best split.

In my second example
(val) => val === true
would match the [{gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}, {gender: "female"}]

Comment: what is your definition of "best split"? More uniformally distributed as in each piece having as equal a length as possible compared to others?

Comment: Best split means that the length of every array would be closer for example
[Array(3), Array(3)]
is better than
[Array(4), Array(2)]

Comment: I have read your question multiple times, but don't see what you mean with *"split it between functions"*, nor what "best" means in *"the best way possible"*. It is nice that you added examples, but it seems like the explanation is missing.

Comment: Hi Trincot.
"the best way possible" means that the number distance (of array length) between each array should be the lowest, and the number of records in each array should be the maximum possible.

Comment: How is it that `[list.filter(e => e.gender === "male"), list.filter(e => e.gender === "female")]` doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Think that the function returns true/false and you are not aware of any logic.

Comment: I think the Asker wants a *partition* of the elements, and the given predicates could be true for multiple list items, so a choice has to be made. This is not clear from the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I understand these requirements.  You have a number of predicate function which you want to use to group your items.  Multiple predicates might return true for the same item, so there are various groupings available.  You want to find a grouping that minimizes the variation in sizes of the results.

I don't find your examples very compelling.  I will try my own.  If your items are `8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]` and you have three predicates: `(n) => n < 7`, `(n) => n > 3`, and `(n) => n % 2 == 1`, then the `8` can only go in the second group (it's greater than 3, but not less than 7 and not odd.)  The `6` can go in either of the first two groups, the `5` could be in any of them, and so on, like this:

```
  8      6       7        5         3     0      9
[[1], [0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2], [0], [1, 2]]
  ^    ^  ^    ^  ^    ^  ^  ^    ^  ^    ^    ^  ^  
  |    |  |    |  |    |  |  |    |  |    |    |  |
  |    +--|----|--|----+--|--|----+--|----+----|--|------> Group 0 (n => n < 7)
  |       |    |  |       |  |       |         |  |
  +-------+----+--|-------+--|-------|---------+--|------> Group 1 (n => n > 3)
                  |          |       |            |
                  +----------+-------+------------+------> Group 2 (n => n % 2 == 1)
```

Since there is one choice for the first, two for the second, two for the third, and so on, the number of possible partitions is `1 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 2`, or `48`.  They might look like this:

```
[//     < 7          > 3      odd
  [ [6, 5, 3, 0], [8, 7, 9], [] ], 
  [ [6, 5, 3, 0], [8, 7],    [9] ], 
  [ [6, 5, 0],    [8, 7, 9], [3] ], 
  [ [6, 5, 0],    [8, 7],    [3, 9] ], 
  // ... (42 rows elided)  
  [ [0],          [8, 6, 9], [7, 5, 3] ], 
  [ [0],          [8, 6],    [7, 5, 3, 9] ]
]
```

Then, from these, we need to pick the ones with the smallest variation in partition size.  We can use statistical variance for this<sup>1</sup>, the sum of the squares of the distances of the values from their mean, so `[[6, 5, 3, 0], [8, 7, 9], []]`, with lengths `4`, `3`, and `0`; this has a variance of `8.667`.  The second one has lengths `4`, `2`, and `1` with a variance of `4.667`.  Our best possibility is `3`, `2` and `2`, with variance of `0.667`.  So an answer like `[[6, 5, 0], [8, 7], [3, 9]]` would be reasonable.  There are probably quite a few with similar behavior; the implementation below simply chooses the first one.

If this correctly describes the problem, then here is some code that I think will handle it:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => Array .from ({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)

const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap ((x, i, a) => f (x, i, a) ? [m (x, i, a)] : [])

const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined
    ? [[]]
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const variance = (ns, avg = sum (ns) / (ns .length || 1)) =>
  sum (ns .map (n => (n - avg) * (n - avg)))

const groupIndices = (count) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x, i) => ((a [x] .push (i)), a), 
    Object .fromEntries (range (0, count) .map (n => [n, []]))
  ))

const specialFunc = (xs, preds) =>
  cartesian (xs .map ((x) => filterMap ((pred, i) => pred (x), (_, i) => i) (preds)))
    .map (groupIndices (preds .length))
    .reduce (
      ({min, v}, xs, _, __, v2 = variance (xs .map (x => x .length))) => 
          v2 < v ? {min: xs, v: v2} : {min, v}, 
      {min: [], v: Infinity}
    ) .min .map (ys => ys .map (i => xs [i]))

console .log (specialFunc (
  [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9], 
  [n => n < 7, n => n > 3, n => n % 2 == 1]
)) //=> [[6, 5, 0], [8, 7], [3, 9]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with some fairly standard utility functions.  **`range`** calculates an integer range inclusive at the bottom, exclusive at the top, so that, for instance, `range (3, 12)` returns  `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10, 11]`.  **`sum`** simply totals an array of numbers, **`filterMap`** combines filtering with mapping, first testing whether an input matches a filter, and if so, transforming the result before putting it in the result.  This implementation is unusual, in that the filter and mapping functions take more than just the value, but also the index and array properties found in things like `map` and `filter`.  We need that as we'll use it to collect indices that match.  (There are plenty of other ways to do that bit, but `filterMap` is a useful, reusable function.)  **`cartesian`** returns the cartesian product of an array of arrays.  For instance, `cartesian ([1, 2, 3], [true], ['a', 'b']])` will return `[[1, true, 'a'], [1, true, 'b'], [2, true, 'a'], [2, true, 'b'], [3, true, 'a'], [3, true, 'b']]`.  And finally `variance` calculate the statistical variance of a list of numbers.

Then we have a helper function, `groupIndices`.  This might be easiest to show with an example.  One of the 48 results from our cartesian product will be `[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]`, which means that our original numbers (`8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]`, recall) are in groups `1`, `0`, `1`, `0`, `2`, `0`, and `1`, respectively.  `groupIndices` takes the number of groups and then takes that cartesian combination, and transforms it into `[[1, 3, 5], [0, 2, 6], [4]]`, giving the *indices* of the values that are mapped to each group.  (If I wasn't out of time, I'm sure we could skip this working with the indices and go directly against the values, but this works.)

Now we hit the main function, that I haven't tried to find a good name for, so is still called `specialFunc`.  That uses `filterMap` to turn our list into `[[1], [0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2], [0], [1, 2]]`, calls `cartesian` on the result, maps `groupIndices` over these values, then uses `reduce` to find (the first) one that is minimal in its variance.  Finally it maps the resulting indices back to the actual values.

Again, we can probably clean this up and work with values not indices, but I would first want to know if this is the sort of behavior you're looking for.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The *standard deviation* has a clearer meaning, but as it's just the square root of the variance, it will be ordered the same way as the variance, and won't involve calculating square roots.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Scott!
Is there a way to initial the result array with data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean when you finish the process you create X amount of array with records.
Would it be possible to use an array with pre-data, and then add to those arrays the final results?
Those array would have to look at the old data in order to split the new records evenly.

A good example would be
specialFunction([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [7,8], [(i) => i ==7, (i) => i === 8]);
We would probably get something like
[1,2,3,7], [1,2,3,8]

Comment: I would almost certainly do that in a separate function, using some kind of `zip` function, run either at the end of this process or between the `map` and `reduce` calls.  While I'm sure it could be added directly to the mix, I think it would simply overcomplicate things.

Comment: But if you do it only after,
You would not know how to split everything the "right way."

Comment: Then do it between, my other option.  Remember that I'm only trying to guess your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitGroups<T>(items: T[], filters: ((x: T) => boolean)[]) {
    let options = filters.map(f => items.filter(f));
    let groups = filters.map((_, index) => ({ data: [] as T[], index }));
    let res: T[][] = [];
    while (options.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a.length, 0) > 0) {
        groups.sort((a, b) => a.data.length - b.data.length);
        let smallGroup = groups[0];
        const smallGroups = groups.filter(g => g.data.length === smallGroup.data.length);
        if (smallGroups.length > 1) {
            smallGroup = smallGroups[Math.floor(Math.random() * (smallGroups.length - 1))];
        }
        if (options[smallGroup.index].length === 0) {
            res.push(smallGroup.data);
            groups = groups.filter(x => x !== smallGroup);
            continue;
        }
        const item = options[smallGroup.index][0];
        options = options.map(x => x.filter(y => y !== item));
        smallGroup.data.push(item);
    }
    res = [...res, ...groups.map(x => x.data)];
    return res;
}

function accurateSplitGroups<T>(items: T[], filters: ((x: T) => boolean)[], times: number) {
    const options: { data: T[][]; diff: number }[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        const res = splitGroups(items, filters);
        let diffBetweenGroups = 0;
        const groupsLens = res.map(x => x.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < groupsLens.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < groupsLens.length; j++) {
                diffBetweenGroups += Math.abs(groupsLens[i] - groupsLens[j]);
            }
        }
        options.push({ data: res, diff: diffBetweenGroups });
    }
    return options.sort((a, b) => a.diff - b.diff)[0].data;
}

const items = [{ gender: 'female' }, { gender: 'female' }, { gender: 'female' }, { gender: 'male' }];
const filters = [(x: any) => !!x.gender, (x: any) => !!x.gender];
const res = accurateSplitGroups(items, filters, 100);
const b = res;
```